# Firebase firestore update running 3 minutes after rest of the function completes

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCP Firebase function set up like this:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore.document('/work_orders/{documentId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

   // code here --
   // then ends like this:

    functions.logger.log('Log Before Interval Start')
    const interval = setInterval(async ()=> {
        if (attachment && attachment_2){ 
            clearInterval(interval)
            functions.logger.log('Attachments Ready')

            const resp = await send_email()
            functions.logger.log('Doc Created', context.params.documentId, newValue)
            functions.logger.log('Resp Created', resp)
            return change.after.ref.update({emailSent: true, createEstimateEmail: false})
    }, 1000)
    functions.logger.log('Log After Interval')
})
```

Everything runs fine. The email sends immediately. But when it comes to `change.after.ref.update` part, that takes around 3 minutes to make that simple commit. And when it finally completes, it triggers the function to run again, since it is `onUpdate`. (The second run exits as soon as it checks the flag as to whether it should run)

Is there a way I can have this commit right away?

*Updated: Logs.*
You can see that 4 minutes later the function is retriggered. This trigger must be due to the updated firestore doc. And you can see it ends immediately, because the function checks `createEstimateEmail` and ends if it is `false`. So, it takes around 4 minutes for that last line to run. (And if I check Firestore using Google Console, it also doesn't update for a few minutes after it finishes running.)

```
2022-01-02 10:30:41.968 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Function execution started
2022-01-02 10:30:44.058 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Log Before Interval Start
2022-01-02 10:30:44.059 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Log After Interval
2022-01-02 10:30:44.124 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Function execution took 2158 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2022-01-02 10:30:45.060 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Attachments Ready
2022-01-02 10:30:45.060 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Attachments Ready
2022-01-02 10:30:51.336 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Doc Created vKFOnZ9usRaDiJ6Nu9Yk
2022-01-02 10:30:51.937 ASTsendEmail51lrasb9sh8s Resp Created [ Response { statusCode: 202, body:....

2022-01-02 10:34:20.391 ASTsendEmail51lrfqr7kldb Function execution started
2022-01-02 10:34:20.402 ASTsendEmail51lrfqr7kldb Function execution took 12 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Comment: Can you also provide the logs? Also include statements and their output in the post, so we can see precisely where the time is going.

Comment: Logs are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it after adding more logging points/logs as suggested by RJC. Essentially, the function was ending before all the work was done.

This answer helped, dealing with setInterval():
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469184/7089055

Final code that works correctly inside the main `onUpdate()` function:

```
    async function waitUntil() {
      return await new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (attachment && attachment_2) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            const msg = {....};
            resolve(msg);
          };
        }, 1000);
      });
    }

    const msg = await waitUntil()
    const resp = await sgMail.send(msg)
    return change.after.ref.update({emailSent: true, createEstimateEmail: false})
```